# Unable to render map as json in Hibernate4Module

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jackson

We are using `jackson-datatype-hibernate` api. Unfortunately we can't render Map objects as JSON. We have debugged the api: this is caused by `keyserialiser` being null.

I'm blocked on this and would appreciate some help.

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serializeFields(MapSerializer.java:472)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:412)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.MapSerializer.serialize(MapSerializer.java:27)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1902)
>   at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
>   at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:161)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:167)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:71)

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the latest versions of these libraries? (because of this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/issues/38)